# Netbeans 6.8 refuses to close

Tags: 10.04, netbeans

I am using netbeans in ubuntu 10.04. After Updation of Netbeans from version 6.8 to version 6.9, Netbeans refuses to close. When I exit Netbeans, it immediately restarts again.

It will constantly do it until I reboot the machine. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards

Comment: I am having the same problem with netbeans on ubuntu 13.10

Comment: @RanaMuhammadWaqas - this question was created for 10.04.  Since you are using a newer version, please create your own question.  Thanks.